Can one distribute data requiring users to sign some non-commercial use agreement and then still add a CC BY-SA license on that downloaded data?
Can one distribute data requiring users to sign some non-commercial use agreement and then still add a CC BY-SA license on that downloaded data? Or does that render the non-commercial use agreement void? Or does that violate the CC BY-SA license? Or some other issue?

Where do you see that the data dump has a CC BY-SA and not a CC BY-NC-SA license or something similar? It could easily be an issue that the CC BY-SA was used in that post out of habit but the actual data dump page has a different license such as CC-BY-NC-SA.

@JoeW eg some text states that the downloaded data is under CC BY-SA license

That doesn't answer the question I asked which was how do you know that is what the actual license is for downloading the data dump and not something put in the post by habit based on what the license is normally on the site? I understand the post that was made says CC BY-SA but as far as I am aware we can't access the new data dump pages yet and those pages could state it as a CC BY-NC-SA license. This is a good question to ask in that question that you linked which others have but as we can't confirm the license that is going to be used this question could be wrong.

@JoeW thanks, assume that some text will state that the downloaded data is under CC BY-SA license. The SE case is just one example. I'd like to know what happens if one distributes data requiring users to sign some non-commercial use agreement and then still add a CC BY-SA license on that downloaded data.

That seems like a pretty big assumption to make when we have no way of verifying what the actual license will be on the data dump before it goes live and becomes available. If you just remove the part about the SE data dump where we don't know what the actual license will be it will greatly improve your question. Just focusing on a the issue of restricting commercial use in a CC BY-SA license will get you the answers you need.

@JoeW ok done but I thought an example would make it clearer.

As a side note if you read the comments on that question and answer you will find that they acknowledge that  they can't stop someone from using that data for commercial use or from sharing it rather they are asking that users don't do that.

@testing-for-ya thanks, good point

Yes
The end user would have a choice over which license they comply with.
Multiple licensing is quite common. For example, Microsoft licenses many of products with personal, educational, commercial, and enterprise versions.

Could downvoters explain?
